# Setting value in a variable in batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

How to set value of `%%~nm` to a variable.
[ie] when I try to set it like `Set "var=%%~nm"` and echo `%var%` .Output is giving *empty string* 
I am facing this issue for all values which has `~`.
Kindly provide a solution .

Answer (score 2):

try this (new variables can't be used in the same for loop without `delayed expansion`:

```
for %%m in (*) do call:doit "%%~nm"
goto:eof

:doit
set "var=%~1"
echo %var%
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo %var%` should work fine when used outside the `for` loop. When you want to echo a variable inside a `for` loop, you have to enable [delayed expansion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx) and use `!var!` (variable is expanded at runtime) instead of `%var%` (variable is expanded at parsetime):

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%m in (*) do (
  set "var=%%~nm"
  echo !var!
)

echo %var%

endlocal
```

If you want to compare a variable to a string, you have to put either both between quotes or none:

```
if %var%==string ...
```

or

```
if "%var%"=="string" ...
```

Otherwise you'd be comparing `string=="string"`, which are obviously not equal.

Comment: I want to use the value of !var! for comaprision   For Eg: If !var!=='Name' Echo name else echo 'Number'. Iam not able to do the comapriosn in If statemtn if I use !var!.Sorry to ask thiis Im new to Dos scripting

Comment: See updated answer. If that doesn't help, update your question with your actual code. This has nothing to do with DOS, BTW.

Comment: @echo off setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion for %%m in (*) do ( set "var=%%~nm" If "!var!"=="Name" echo !var!) endlocal.when i m comparing like this this is not working I want to compare in the fforr  lloooop onnlly

Comment: "It's not working" is an insufficient problem description. Please update your question with your actual code, sample input and the expected output.